# XSLT include with different namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have a problem with XSLT mixing namespaces. I want to create some shared templates for different projects which are in the namespace "doc", and call them for example from namespace "map", but this doesn't work. Is there any way to do this?

map.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.example.com/map"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/map map.xsd">
    <node>
        <short>Short description</short>
        <long>Long description <br/> needs a lot of space</long>
    </node>
    <node>
        <short>Another short description</short>
        <long>Another long description <br/> also needs a lot of space_</long>
    </node>
</root>
```

map.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/map"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com/map"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.example.com/doc"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <import namespace="http://www.example.com/doc" schemaLocation="doc.xsd"/>

    <element name="root">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="node" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <complexType>
                        <sequence>
                            <element name="short" type="normalizedString" />
                            <element name="long">
                                <complexType mixed="true">
                                    <sequence>
                                        <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                            <element ref="doc:br" />
                                        </choice>
                                    </sequence>
                                </complexType>    
                            </element>
                        </sequence>
                    </complexType>
                </element>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>

    <!-- make imported elements from documentation public available -->
    <element name="br" substitutionGroup="doc:br"/>
</schema>
```

doc.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/doc"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com/doc"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <element name="br"></element>
</schema>
```

The xml file validates using this schema files.

map.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform http://www.w3.org/2007/schema-for-xslt20.xsd"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.example.com/doc"
    xmlns:map="http://www.example.com/map" >
    <xsl:import href="doc.xsl" />

    <!-- output method is .tex file, no xml -->
    <xsl:output method="text" media-type="application/x-tex" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="map:root">
        <xsl:text>\begin{Root}{&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="map:node" />
        <xsl:text>\end{Root}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="map:node">
        <xsl:text>\begin{Node}&#xd;&#xa;{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="map:short" />
        <xsl:text>}&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="map:long" />
        <xsl:text>&#xd;&#xa;\end{Node}&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="map:short">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="map:long">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text() | doc:br" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

doc.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform http://www.w3.org/2007/schema-for-xslt20.xsd"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.example.com/doc" >    

    <xsl:template match="doc:br">
        <xsl:text> \\&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- copy unspecific text, escape before -->
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="normalize-space(replace(., '(&amp;|%|\$|#|_)', '\\$1'))" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using this templates, the transformation works, but it doesn't produce the disered output.

Generated output:

```
\begin{Root}{
\begin{Node}
{Short description}
Long description needs a lot of space
\end{Node}
\begin{Node}
{Another short description}
Another long description also needs a lot of space\_
\end{Node}
\end{Root}
```

Desired output:

```
\begin{Root}{
\begin{Node}
{Short description}
Long description needs a lot of space
\end{Node}
\begin{Node}
{Another short description}
Another long description also \\
needs a lot of space\_
\end{Node}
\end{Root}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your `map.xml` input document all elements in that document are in the same namespace `http://www.example.com/map`, including the `br` elements. So I don't see why your imported stylesheet matching a `br` element in a different namespace should help with that input document. You would need to write a template matching `map:br` if you want to transform those elements.

Comment: I just don't want to rewrite the transformation of doc:br, but reuse it in multiple other namespaces. In XSD, I have done this with substitutionGroup, is there any similar possibility in XSLT?

Comment: I am not aware of any way with normal XSLT to take into account any schema info, in terms of namespaces the `br` elements you have are in the same namespace as the other elements and I don't see why the schema matters. On the other hand, XSLT 2 and 3 support schema-aware processing, I am not familiar enough with that to tell whether you can somehow write a match pattern to take your schema substitution into account, https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-schema-element-test talks about that, so if you are using a schema-aware processor like Saxon EE have a read or what for @michaelkay to help.

Comment: The schema was just for clarification. I know that the <br> in the xml file is a map:br as well as all the other elements in the xml file, the problem is just that i want to reuse the doc:br element. For example, I have one project in the map namespace and one in the maptwo namespace, which are independent, but I want to use the implementation of doc:br in both of them. In schema I can do this with substitution, but I don't know how to do this in XSLT 2.0. Shema can't be used in the XSLT processor, I use Saxon HE.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand at all what you want to achieve. Perhaps simply using `<xsl:template match="map:br | doc:br">...</xsl:template>` suffices to implement the same transformation for two different elements from different namespaces. There is also `*:br` to match namespace agnostically.

Comment: Another option would be to give that template matching `doc:br` an additional name attribute (e.g. `name="foo"`) and then you could use `<xsl:template match="map:br"><xsl:call-template name="foo"/></xsl:template>`.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you, haven't thought about that. At the moment I have solved the problem using *:br in doc.xsl, but maybe I will switch to named templates if I use multiple shared resources.

Answer (score 0):

According to [XSLT include with different namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47451271/xslt-include-with-different-namespaces/47458224?noredirect=1#comment81872957_47458224) I modified doc.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform http://www.w3.org/2007/schema-for-xslt20.xsd"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.example.com/doc" >    

    <xsl:template match="*:br">
        <xsl:text> \\&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- copy unspecific text, escape before -->
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="normalize-space(replace(., '(&amp;|%|\$|#|_)', '\\$1'))" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Another possibility would be the usage of named templates and then calling them from the main xsl file as he also suggested.